# Relative position of vowels in a word.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways the letters of the ARRANGE can be arranged taking all at a time such that the ***relative position*** of vowels and consonants is constant.

I could think of solving this question from two perspectives

1. Keeping the position of vowels in the word (i.e. 1st, 4th & last position) fixed only for vowels, this way the position of vowels could be interchanged i.e. vowels can occupy each other's position without any restriction. It'll quite easy to solve taking this approach. The words formed may include ERRANGA, ARRENGA, AGRANRE etc etc
2. Since the term ***Relative position*** is used in the question, we must keep the position o the vowels and consonant constant relative to each other. Which means that all the words formed must have two vowels on the left side of E, one on either sides of A and two in the right of the other A and same with the consonant. *I have no idea how to solve the question taking this approach.*

Which one should I go for?

Comment: I would go with your first interpretation.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @GerryMyerson. Using this approach, if the vowels were all distinct, and the consonants, were all distinct, you would ask yourself: in how many ways can the $3$ vowels be permuted, and in how many ways can the $4$ consonants be permuted?  In this problem however, two of the vowels are identical, which requires an over-counting adjustment factor of $\frac{1}{2!}$.  The consideration re the consonants is similar.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1TAp4suDPnpbRYRT7TThbEK__NAUGKgQV

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1PuEE-9LTvIIS2ASFisJdHqXdB7eP2Jhs?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1MEjJ1x8aDDdzOniGG14Z94f5HNKqMHzC?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1HERkdLYAjDCLLeaXTAJRwDwVFWY8qFLl?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TwCjCQN-vPLqmKFPkSOV6cjnDnnI2QE9

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IdJyw1siXHTsQQQBaQudb9CVGFP8f_Y_/view